# Setting the default value of field to the value of a parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, lightswitch-2012

I am using lightswitch and i was able to set a default value for a field using the Created() method. Now I can explicitly set this value. My query has a parameter that filters it. I want to set my default value of the field to which ever dynamic value is going to be supplied. how do i do that? Below is what i have..

```
partial void Payperiod_Created()
{

    this.EstateID = 5;
}
```

Edited

I created a method method in  `public partial class sspDataService` .. the data serivce class that is going to return the value that i want. My intention here was to create a global variable.

```
public string estateName()
{

    string esName = "";
    string uName = this.Application.User.Identity.Name;
    try
    {
        var qryUser =

            this.aspnet_Users.Where(a => (a.UserName == uName)).SingleOrDefault();
        esName = qryUser.PayGroup;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine(e.InnerException.ToString());
    }
    return esName;
}
```

However i cannot access this method inside my `Payperiod_Created()` method. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate? (Specifically, how will the value be *supplied*?)

For the method specifically, you simply need to pass the value into the method itself, so that the definition for your method becomes :

```
partial void Payperiod_Created(int newVal)
{
    this.EstadeID = newVal;
}
```

And then wherever you call the method you include the new value :

```
Payperiod_Created(5);    //this will EstateID to 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You might declare the parameter as an Nullable Int (int?) whcih is a variable type that accepts either null or int values. Then check for null value provided, if is is null then you can set as the default value:

```
public void ExecuteQuery(int? myParam)
{
   EstateId = myParam ?? EstateId;
   // Execute your query...
}
```

Now, expression `EstateId = myParam ?? EstateId;` is an IsNull operator, equivalent to "set EstateId value to myParam values, unless it is null, which then set it to whatever EstateId values now", or in other words to:

```
if(myParam != null) { EstateId = myParam; }
```